# From [String: Any] to "Key = Value" String in Swift

Tags: swift, struct, iteration

I have a struct which consist of some elements which are in `String`, `Bool` and `Int` lets call it `Struct A`. I also have an another struct lets called it `Struct B`.

```
Struct A{
let name: String
let surname: String
let age: Int   
}

Struct B{
let columnId: Int
let value: String
}
```

I have an array of B and I want to assign values of A to B. Example array;

> FirstElement(columnId:1,value:"name=myname")
>   SecondElement(columnId:2,value:"surname=mysurname")
>   ThirdElement(columnId:3,value:"age=20")

I can get all properties of a struct with below extension;

```
extension Loopable {
func allProperties() throws -> [String: Any] {

    var result: [String: Any] = [:]

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

    // Optional check to make sure we're iterating over a struct or class
    guard let style = mirror.displayStyle, style == .struct || style == .class else {
        throw NSError()
    }

    for (property, value) in mirror.children {
        guard let property = property else {
            continue
        }

        result[property] = value
    }

    return result
}
}
```

After I get the all properties I want some kind of iteration; **My question** is that how can I get value and key like "value=key" string in below "classA[i]"

```
 func setArray(){
 let classA = classA().getAllProperties()
    for i in 0..<deviceLogs.count{
        myArray.append(B(columnId: i, value: classA[i]) )
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I want to get all the properties with its values inside Struct A and use it as String for value property when creating Struct B object.

Comment: classA["name"] is not working?

Comment: If you have to use `Mirror`, you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your setArray function

```
func setArray(){
    let keysArray = Array(classA.keys)
    let valuesArray = Array(classA.values)

    let classA = classA().getAllProperties()
    for i in 0..<deviceLogs.count{
        let valueString = keysArray[i] + "=" + valuesArray[i]
        myArray.append(B(columnId: i, value: valueString) )
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I have only one question. Can we be sure that keysArray and valuesArray will be same in all situations. I mean first value of keys array equals to values arrays first key?

Comment: By definition, a dictionary has no order. So I would recommend you to eventually improve your data structure instead of using a dictionary. In your allProperties function, you are creating a dictionary called result.

Comment: Aaa ok sorry. Actually, I guess, this is not a bad approach. I'm just not sure If both arrays' has same order every time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this

```
struct B {
    let columnId: Int
    let value: Any
}

protocol Properties {
    var allProperties: [Any] { get }
}

extension Properties {
    var allProperties: [Any] {
        return Mirror(reflecting: self).children.flatMap { $0 }
    }
}    

struct A: Properties {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Here is the example how you can use it:

```
let properties = A(name: "name", surname: "surname", age: 18).allProperties
```

**// NOTE: your `value` property in `B` should be of type `Any` in place of `String`**

```
var list = [B]()
for (index, property) in properties.enumerated() {
    list.append(B(columnId: index, value: property))
}
```